# ArrayList add Elements

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm a absolute beginner in Java and I searched for half an hour, but I just can't figure out why the following code won't compile:

```
  public class Main {
      ArrayList<Integer> path = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      path.add(0);
      path.add(1);
      Out.print(path);
  }
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have any ***methods***?

Comment: No its all in the main class

Comment: Please open any Java tutorial and look at least at one sample of code.

Comment: Can you add the error that comes up when you try to compile?

Comment: 4 times identifier expected, and 2 times illegal start of type

Comment: You cannot put statements like that directly in the class body. You need to put them in a method. I suggest you [start right here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below specified snippet:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestString {
    public static void main(String[] args){
      ArrayList<Integer> path = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      path.add(0);
      path.add(1);
      System.out.print(path);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please refer to https://www.guru99.com/java-tutorial.html for basic java related informations.